# tKafkaInput : SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: talend

I am trying to read my JSON message from kafka topic and I write to JSON file.
I am getting the following error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/TOS_BD-20160704_1411-V6.2.1/TOS_BD-20160704_1411-V6.2.1/workspace/.Java/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/TOS_BD-20160704_1411-V6.2.1/TOS_BD-20160704_1411-V6.2.1/workspace/.Java/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See  for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Here is my job

[image]

How to solve this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Activate `Window / Show Views`, then select `Talend / Modules`.

Now check if `tKafkaInput` is available twice. If it is, try going to `Help / Installation Details / Features` or `Plugins` and see if you can disable the unwanted component.

It could also be a bug from Talend. Since no version number was available this couldn't be checked.

Comment: Yes it is there.
I am using Open Studio Big Data  (6.2).
Let me check how to uninstall repeated components.

As you suggested `plugins` contains a single entry so I cannot remove it.
But modules contains multiple entries , so I have to get rid of it.